# How to send payload using body of a GET request with drf-spectacular?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I'm writing an API using Django REST Framework. I'm sending some data using the body of a GET request and everything is working fine. Now I'm using drf-spectacular to generate SwaggerUI and ReDoc but I don't know how to make it do the request like that.

I've tried making a POST request and everything works fine, but with a GET it appends the parameters to the URL or to the curl header. I want drf-spectacular to puts the parameters into the body of the curl.

So how do you tell drf-spectacular that the curl needs to put the parameters into the body of a GET request?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.